# Handling get response while server has been crashed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have a question.
I send a Get request by Ajax every second and expect to get some response from the server.

In the case and my application crashes and I continue to send Get request every second, I don't get any response until receiving the server's timeout error (an error code 502.) .

If somebody knows how I can handle this moment between sending the get requests every second and until receiving error code 502.

Thanks

Comment: You probably shouldn't send another request until your previous one has finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server is down, whatever you are using for the ajax call should have errored out... in which case you should handle it with a call back or a catch block. There, you should handle what you will do on the frontend based on the response.

As far as not sending out more requests, there really is no way to know for sure. For all your code knows, the server is particularly slow at that moment.